# .NET CORE 3.1 Why buttons tag render as disabled by default?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm having a problem very weird... I'm developing a.Net Core Web App (3.1). The problem is: a lot of buttons in almost all my Views, are rendered in Chrome as Disabled!!!!

Here the code of button:

```
<form method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" width: 250px asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create">Nuevo</button>
</form>
```

However, when debugging, in Chrome I get this:

```
<form method="post">
       <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" width:="" 250px="" formaction="/Product/Create" disabled="disabled">Nuevo</button>
</form>
```

The buttons are disabled! `disabled="disabled"`

I don't know why!!! This is happening with a bunch of buttons
It even happens with views that I have not modified, for example the Login button on default Login razor page from .Net Core Identity.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I have a button's custom tag helper.
Even when a button tag haven't the custom tag. This last one is fired with all buttons...

```
namespace BBDWeb.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("button")]
    public class DisableButton: TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-is-disabled")]
        public DateTime? Fecha { set; get; } = null;

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (Fecha<=DateTime.Today)
            {
                var d = new TagHelperAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                output.Attributes.Add(d);
            }
            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```